# Java Swing / AWT - Best way to create a scrollpane section?

Tags: java, swing, loops, awt, scrollpane

I'm creating a small social network for my programming class in Java Swing and AWT.
I'm trying to create a ScrollPane that can contain posts from users. If the posts go out of the window, i want to be able to scroll through the posts (see image attached). What would be the best approach? Do i need to use a scrollpane, Jtable, JSlider? 
[image]
On the image i have a pane on the left that works as a menu. I also have a pane on the right, which is where i want the posts (example image was made in Photoshop). The posts is being created by a loop.

I haven't included any code, since I'm just asking for the best approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this specific approach I suggest this:

Use [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for the right section, that changes based on which button you click on the left section.

The left one would be a [`BoxLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) with vertical alignment.

For each of the panels on the `CardLayout`, you add a `JScrollPane` so they are all independent from each other.

And for the main panel I'd suggest a [`GridLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) so you can have both panes equally spaced.

Comment: You can also add the sections in `JScrollPane`s inside a `JSplitPane` so the users will drag the divider according to their needs.

Comment: @Frakcool thanks for the reply, really helpful! What container would you put each post inside? I tried setting it up like this: 1 scrollpanel with 10 jpanels that each had 1 post inside. But even though the 10 jpanels went out of the screen vertically, the scroller didn't appear. Should I use something else than jpanels for that to work?

Comment: Then post a proper [mre] in a new question so that we can help you. This question was about "which layouts to use". The new question is "why the scroll bar doesn't appear when you have 5+ posts"

Comment: @Frakcool Great idea, i've done that now. Thanks for your help!